# How to set_gid() for each bubble in matplot scatter chart?

Tags: matplotlib, scatter

I draw a scatter chart by below codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [2,4,6]
y = [1,3,7]
r = [650,890,320]
clr = ['r','b','g']
bubble_id = ['C0','C1','C2']

H0 = plt.scatter(x,y,s=r,c=clr)
```

[image: bubbles of matplotlib scatter chart]

Then I want to `'set_gid()'` to the three bubbles as `'C0', 'C1' ,'C2'` respectively. How to do that ? As `H0` is a single object `<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x0ADA6D30>`, I don't know how to break down H0 and find the three 'bubble son' of H0 . Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I know that might not be the most efficient solution, but what about looping?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools as it

X = [2,4,6]
Y = [1,3,7]
radius = [650,890,320]
clr = ['r','b','g']
bubble_id = ['C0','C1','C2']

ax = plt.subplot(111)
for x, y, r, c, id in it.izip(X, Y, radius, clr, bubble_id):
    ax.scatter(x,y,s=r,c=c, gid=id)
```

visually gives the same plot.

In Ipython I've given a look at `PathCollection` methods, and it looks like there is no trivial way to get out the single patches from it.

**Edit in year 2020**

Since nowadays your are very likely using python 3 (if not you should), it is possible to use the built-in `zip` instead of `itertools.izip`.
Thank you @Guimoute for reviving the answer

Comment: Is there a reason to use `itertools.izip` instead of the built-in `zip`?

Comment: Nowadays you can just use `zip`, but when I wrote the answer python 2.7 was probably used more than python 3 and `zip` there returns a list and not an iterable. For the example at hand doesn't make much of a difference, thought

Comment: Ah my bad, I did not check the year! I guess it's a good reflex to always "actively" use iterators and avoid more expensive calculations.