# plot many circles based on x,y,r being vectors in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

x,y are positions of the circles and r is the radius - all vectors.I want to plot them all at once. Something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches Circle

#define x,y,r vectors

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.Circle((x,y),r,color='r')
plt.show()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the radius a 'data space' coordinate, with the same units as x and y?  If so, the "circles" will only appear as true circles when the aspect ratio of the plot is 1.  If the radius is not related to x and y, and you just want circular markers (regardless of the aspect ratio of the plot), @FrancescoMontesano's answer should work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not informed about the Circles patch, but here is how you can do it with the standard plot command:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0.2,0.4])
y = np.array([0.2,1.2])
r = np.array([0.5,0.3])

phi = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi,100)

na=np.newaxis

# the first axis of these arrays varies the angle, 
# the second varies the circles
x_line = x[na,:]+r[na,:]*np.sin(phi[:,na])
y_line = y[na,:]+r[na,:]*np.cos(phi[:,na])

plt.plot(x_line,y_line,'-')
plt.show()
```

The basic idea is to give the `plt.plot(...)` command two 2D arrays. In that case they are interpreted as a list of plots. Espacially for many plots (=many circles) this is much faster, than plotting circle by circle.

Answer (score 1):

[plt.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) allows you to define a radius of the points plotted.

From the doc

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x, y, s=20, c='b', marker='o')
[...]

s:
    size in points^2. It is a scalar or an array of the same length as x and y.
```

Playing with `facecolor` and `edgecolor` you should be able to get what you want

You can find an example in [How to set_gid() for each bubble in matplot scatter chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687089/how-to-set-gid-for-each-bubble-in-matplot-scatter-chart)

Comment: an alterantive is: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.html

Comment: x and y is in 'meters' coordinates and so is r. They are all of equal length. One radius for each point. I do want markers being circles I suppose but I want them to be of variable size x[i],y[i] with radius r[i].

Comment: with `scatter` you can give a different radius per point. With `marker=o` you are sure that they will be circle, whatever you do. If you want physical sizes, you can use @tcaswell link with `Circle` but with the warning of @warren